# React: Google Map API not using passed Lon and Lat to render Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm passing my props from my parent component to my child component.  In the props along with a bunch of other things is my Longitude and Latitude that my Google Maps component should render.  Now when I try to render, my console says this for both setPostion and setCenter:

```
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

I've checked and made sure my numbers were actually numbers, even went as far as ParseFloat()ing them before they're rendered, and now I just get a blank canvas.

Please help.  First code attached is my GoogleMapComponent that is called whenever the lat and long is passed:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Map extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const google = window.google;
    let gMap = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {
        lat: this.props.lat,
        lng: this.props.lon
      }
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: this.props.lat,
        lng: this.props.lon
      },
      map: gMap,
      title: "Hello World!"
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="mapped" ref="map" />;
  }
}

export default Map;
```

and this here is my code that I pass the map component to and should render the lat and lon.  When looking at the code, keep in mind my lat and lon being passed through

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Map from "./mapcomponent";

class SingleEvent extends Component {
  render() {
    let {
      situation,
      time,
      day,
      date,
      address0,
      address1,
      address2,
      venue,
      Lon,
      Lat
    } = this.props.activeEvent;
    return (
      <div className="single-event">
        <div className="calendar-container">
          <h4>{day}</h4>
          <h4>{date}</h4>
          <h4> {time} </h4>
        </div>
        <div className="details">
          <div className="ceremony-container">
            <h1>{situation}</h1>
            <h2>{address0}</h2>
            <h3>{address1}</h3>
            <h3>{address2}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="images">
            <img src={venue} alt="something" />
            <Map ref="mapped" lon={Lon} lat={Lat} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleEvent;
```

Comment: Did you log the `typeof` value of the `this.prop.lat` and `this.prop.lon` in the GoogleMapComponent?

Comment: Doesnt look like there is a problem unless the value u get from the props is not a number. Try an if condition to render the map only if typeof Lat is a number

Comment: Longitude in Google Maps  in known as Lng not Lon...fixing that may help getting it properly recognized as lng= longitude